# Repeat variables by date when combing 2 dataframes

Tags: r

if I have a two data frames I'm combining

```
Date         RollingSTD
01/06/2012   0.16
01/07/2012   0.18
01/08/2012   0.17
01/09/2012   0.16
```

and

```
Date         DivRate
01/06/2012   0.20
04/08/2012   0.23
```

I am trying to combine them in such a way that repeats the dividend rate until it reaches a date where the rate changes, such as this;

```
Date         RollingSTD  DivRate
01/06/2012   0.16        0.20
01/07/2012   0.18        0.20
01/08/2012   0.17        0.20
01/09/2012   0.16        0.23
```

can it be done in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case BluVoxe is wrong in assuming that your 2012-08-04 date is a typo, you can easily get round it with a full join...

```
df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = "Date") %>%    #will include all dates in either df
  arrange(Date) %>%                  #sort by date
  fill(DivRate) %>%                  #fill down NAs
  filter(!is.na(RollingSTD))         #remove the dates only in df2

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Date       RollingSTD DivRate
  <date>          <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2012-06-01       0.16    0.2 
2 2012-07-01       0.18    0.2 
3 2012-08-01       0.17    0.2 
4 2012-09-01       0.16    0.23
```

Comment: Hi, you're correct that this wasn't a typo however i'm still getting some NA's where I shouldn't and some wrong variables in places too

Comment: @LukeAJN, it seems you've oversimplified your problem.  The code above has no problem until and unless there are some other factors/variables present in your data, which are not available in the `minimal` example

Comment: @AnilGoyal yes that's what I had presumed I had done.  I might try play around with it a while longer and try get it working as the code above has about 80% of it filled in correctly

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, it looks like you first need to transform the `Date` column in the second table as follows:

- If a date's 'day' part is > 1 it should be bumped to the first day of the following month
- Otherwise it should stay the same

You can then 'join' the two datasets and use `tidyr::fill()` to achieve the desired result.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

# Some example data
df1 <- tibble(
  Date = as_date("2012-06-01") %m+% months(0:3),
  RollingSTD = c(.16, .18, .17, .16)
)

df2 <- tibble(
  Date = as_date(c("2012-06-01", "2012-08-04")),
  DivRate = c(.2, .23)
)

# Transform the 'Date' column to be its monthly ceiling
df2_transformed <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(Date = ceiling_date(Date, "month", change_on_boundary = 0))

# Perform the join and fill
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2_transformed, by = "Date") %>% 
  fill(DivRate)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Date       RollingSTD DivRate
#>   <date>          <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 2012-06-01       0.16    0.2 
#> 2 2012-07-01       0.18    0.2 
#> 3 2012-08-01       0.17    0.2 
#> 4 2012-09-01       0.16    0.23
```

Comment: Hi, it actually wasn't a typo as the Dividends can change on dates that aren't 01/mm/yy while the rolling std are all on 01/mm/yy

Comment: Aha! My mistake, thanks for clarifying. I will update my solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**
I made some modification to my solution so that it meets your requirement. For this purpose I shelved the idea of `left_join`ing two data sets in favor of `full_join` as suggested by Mr. @Andrew Gustar for which I am thankful. Then you
can use `na.locf` function from `zoo` package that replaces `NA` values with the most recent non-`NA` values. After that I discarded every `Date` values not corresponding to the original `Date` in `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)

# We actually only use lubridate to be able to arrange Date column values 
# later otherwise we will get misleading results. 
df %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) -> df

df1 %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) -> df1

df %>%
  full_join(df1, by = "Date") %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(across(DivRate, ~ na.locf(.x))) %>%
  filter(Date %in% df$Date)


        Date RollingSTD DivRate
1 2012-06-01       0.16    0.20
2 2012-07-01       0.18    0.20
3 2012-08-01       0.17    0.20
4 2012-09-01       0.16    0.23
```

Comment: Hi, it actually wasn't a typo as the Dividends can change on dates that aren't 01/mm/yy while the rolling std are all on 01/mm/yy

Comment: So in that case you expect  `DivRate`s to remain in `0.20`? You can still use this code but there has to be an indication of a change in `DivRate`.

Comment: I would indeed expect the DivRate to stay at 0.2 on the 01/08/2012 but then change to 0.23 on 01/09/2012.  I'll try your code and indicate a change in DivRate like you say.  Thanks!